# Implementing a loop

Tags: python

This code works fine, but is there a way to reduce the duplicate code with a loop?

I know it is very basic. I've used Python2.7

```
if List[3] == answer[3]:  
    self.score = int(self.score) + 1  
    self.questions = self.questions + 1  
    info = info + 1  
    self.update()          
else:  
    self.questions = self.questions + 1  
    self.update()  
          
if List[4] == answer[4]:  
    self.score = int(self.score) + 1  
    self.questions = self.questions + 1  
    info = info + 1  
    self.update()  
else:  
    self.questions = self.questions + 1  
    self.update()
```

If there a way to use a loop? The lists are both compared from `[0]` to `[5]`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Read about [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (particularly [how to create a good example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) in order to get responses.

Comment: I'm hesitant to give you too much help because you'll learn less that way, but a for loop can be used to make this simpler.  You might want to `zip()` the two lists together

Comment: I'll keep an eye on this post, let me know if you have any other specific questions

Answer (score 2):

```
for x, y in zip(List, answer):
    if x == y:
        self.score = int(self.score) + 1
        self.questions = self.questions + 1
        info = info + 1
        self.update()
    else:
        self.questions = self.questions + 1
        self.update()
```

Comment: Why use `zip`? Does it add anything useful besides packing and immediately unpacking it?

Comment: I think it looks nicer too, and it's ever so slightly more efficient.  And it helps you learn something new

Comment: @Drise That's the Pythonic way to do it. Also, it builds all pairs, not missing the last one like yours.

Answer (score 0):

Should be pretty simple:

```
for i in range(5 + 1):
    if List[i] == answer[i]:  
        self.score = int(self.score) + 1  
        self.questions = self.questions + 1  
        info = info + 1  
        self.update()          
    else:  
        self.questions = self.questions + 1  
        self.update()
```